# How to get Flink Operator State TTL to work

Tags: java, testing, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am not able to get the operator state TTL to work. I have set the TTL to 5 minutes so after that time, I am expecting the state to be cleared. When I notice the state is empty because of the TTL expiry, it should refresh the state

```
public static class TestFilter extends RichFilterFunction<A>
      implements CheckpointedFunction {
    final Helper helper;
    final ConfigFetcher configFetcher;
    private final ListStateDescriptor<Integer> listStateDescriptor =
        new ListStateDescriptor<>(
            "state_descriptor", TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<>() {}));

    @SuppressWarnings("NullAway.Init")
    private transient ListState<Integer> listState;

    TestFilter(
        Helper helper,
        ConfigFetcher configFetcher) {
      this.helper = helper;
      this.configFetcher = configFetcher;
    }

    @Override
    public void initializeState(FunctionInitializationContext context) throws Exception {
      StateTtlConfig stateTTLConfig =
          StateTtlConfig.newBuilder(Time.minutes(5))
              .setUpdateType(StateTtlConfig.UpdateType.OnCreateAndWrite)
              .setStateVisibility(StateTtlConfig.StateVisibility.NeverReturnExpired)
              .build();
      stateDescriptor.enableTimeToLive(stateTTLConfig);
      state =          
       context.getOperatorStateStore().getListState(stateDescriptor);
    }

    @Override
    public void snapshotState(FunctionSnapshotContext context) {}

    @Override
    public boolean filter(A element) throws Exception {
        Set<Integer> ids = new HashSet<>();
        if (listState.get() == null) {
          ids = configFetcher.getIds();
          listState.update(new ArrayList<>(ids));
        } else {
          listState.get().forEach(ids::add);
          if (ids.isEmpty()) {
            ids = configFetcher.getIds();
            listState.update(new ArrayList<>(ids));
          }
        }
        return ids.contains(element)
    
    }
```

When I test this, I notice that after the 5 min, the state is not being cleared/refreshed. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that state TTL is only supported for keyed state. The implementation doesn't handle operator state.

This is why, in the documentation, State TTL is a subsection underneath Using Keyed State: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.18/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/state/#state-time-to-live-ttl

Answer (score 0):

The `initializeState()` function is more commonly used in situations where you might need to handle custom recovery logic or initialize the contents of the state. You may want to define your state within the `open()` function which is generally used for initial operator configuration similar to the following:

```
public class TestFun extends RichFilterFunction<A> implements CheckpointedFunction {
    @SuppressWarnings("NullAway.Init")
    private transient ListState<Integer> listState;

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
        StateTtlConfig stateTTLConfig =
          StateTtlConfig.newBuilder(Time.minutes(5))
              .setUpdateType(StateTtlConfig.UpdateType.OnCreateAndWrite)
              .setStateVisibility(StateTtlConfig.StateVisibility.NeverReturnExpired)
              .build();
      stateDescriptor.enableTimeToLive(stateTTLConfig);
      listState = runtimeContext.getListState(stateDescriptor);
    }
}
```

Additionally, it looks like your previous example references `state` however you only appear to define a `listState`. If you have multiple references to each of these, you'll need to ensure that you are setting/reading from the correct one.

Comment: I cannot get operator state from within open() though. The runtimeContext.getListState gives me errors that I need to be using a keyed state. The reason why I used the CheckpointedFunction is because I want a non-keyed state. Is there a way to get operator state within open()?

Comment: I hadn't realized that your operator in this case was not a keyed operator. As @David Anderson mentioned, this isn't supported out of keyed state. You could explicitly key your stream prior to this to leverage that (which could be a very heavy-handed approach), if you absolutely needed this.